# Beautiful HH-pattern. Find it

Tags: pattern

Knowing the solution I consider this pattern as a quite beautiful.

> Find the pattern:
>    HH,EL,IB,EB,CN,OF,NE,NA,MG,AL,SI,PS,CL,AR,KC,AS,CT, ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IV,CR,MN,FE...

Solution:

> The NE...SI bunch in the middle seem to indicate the periodic table. Bringing one up shows that this is all the elements' symbols in periodic table order, taken two letters at a time.

Comment: I added a spoiler, to help others not see the explanation right away. Please rollback if you see this as not useful.